# What mechanism does Web Deploy 3.0 use to guarantee an atomic deployment with non downtime?

Tags: iis, deployment, iis-7, web

What mechanism does Web Deploy 3.0 use to guarantee an atomic deployment with non downtime?

"Atomic" meaning that clients requests are either processed by the current version or the the newly deployed version. This is complicated due to dependencies external to the web app (such as database changes)

"No downtime" means that HTTP requests are only delayed during deployment as opposed to receiving offline or 503 responses.

Comment: Related issue: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/3475062-make-webdeploy-transactional

Comment: It seems like this is actually **not** a feature of Web Deploy, then.